# Long to String in java

Tags: java, string

There is a code :

```
    Long val = 10L
```

If I want to take its value  as a String which approach is correct?

`val.toString()` or `(String)val`?

Comment: Did you test if `(String)val` even works?

Comment: (String) val was giving runtime error. I was confused on this. BUt yes String.valueOf is working perfectly. I just wanted to cover the null condition also. In , toString() I had to do that manually.

Comment: So do you understand now why (String) val does not work?

Comment: (String) vale is called a 'cast', you are trying to convince the compiler that your Long is a derivative of String. Since this is not true it should give a compiler error (not a runtime error).

Answer (score 4):

`val.toString()` would work.

If you are not sure if `val` can be null, you can also do `String.valueOf(val)`

Comment: One comment to make is that calling `String.valueOf(val)` would rely on unboxing a `Long` into a primitive `long`.

Comment: Thanks. String.valueOf is exactly what I wanted. I wanted to cover the null case also.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: That would be bad (result in NPE). Why won't it call String.valueOf(Object) without unboxing?

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it like this with the String class:

```
String s = String.valueOf(val);
```

If your Long might be null and you don't want to get a 4-letter "null" string, you might use Objects.toString, like: String s = Objects.toString(val, null);

You reverse it using `Long val = Long.parseLong(String);` but in this direction you need to catch NumberFormatException

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
    Long.toString(val);
```

A typecast does not work since String is not a primitive datatype.